# Transactional Email Compatible with CiviCRM (Not Sendgrid)

Tags: mailing

We started having trouble with mass mailings at the start of 2018. CiviCRM's tracking did not yield helpful information: mailing reports state 100% of emails were delivered, and I knew this to be inaccurate.

I set up Sendgrid, and for first four months had excellent delivery rates. In May, 14% of our emails were blocked. After a lot of conversations with Sendgrid support, it turns out this is because others on our shared IP have spammy practices.

the price to solve this is to have a dedicated IP at $80/month. This is steep for us, like other many CiviCRM users, we are a very small nonprofit. (also, I resent being extorted. We chose a plan because of how many emails we send; had I been informed that we would receive poor service at that price, I would have made a different choice.)

But looking around, I do not see other email platforms that are as easily compatible with CiviCRM. SendinBlue, for instance, has plugins for CMSs, but not CRMs.

Does anyone have a good experience with a transactional email service? Or suggestions on how to see more accurate tracking from CiviCRM?

Comment: would it be worth considering shifting hosting? all our hosted sites are on servers where mailings just go directly via our servers so no need for extra links in the chain - and i presume we wouldn't be the only ones offering that

Comment: I've heard lots of people get on well with [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) but haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a good experience using SparkPost and MailJet for both transactional and CiviMail use.

SparkPost extension:
https://civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost-civicrm-integration

MailJet extension:
https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.mailjet
Though note, this is old code for version 4.4 and needed a change to get it working in a 4.6 install where I used it. Off the top of my head a core Mailing file was overwritten by the extension but it doesn't need to be to work in 4.6.

Comment: +1 on Sparkpost - we've had a great experience; I don't think you even need the Civi extension

Comment: I have a client who uses Mailjet. It works well, and it's not too expensive (see mailjet.com/pricing). For my client it was also important that their servers were located in the EU. I haven't configured bounce processing yet.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that from my perspective if you find a good service but integration with CiviCRM is lacking you have two options:

1. You either start making this integration yourself, or pay someone to make it for you. You then share what you have made
2. Or you stick with the options which are working for the moment. Which @oskylark has helped you with.